# Static HTML not rendered Cloud 9 node express/socket project

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cloud9-ide

I am trying a node express/socket.io project in Cloud 9.
I have the following project structure

├── server.js
                                                                                                                                                                               ├── appconstants.js
├── public
    └──landing.js
├── views
    └──landing.html

we are using `app.use(express.static(__dirname));`

I am able to reach the .js files by accessing if from URL directly, but .html file path from url gives empty response.

The http response code to .html (get) was 200 in server.

hostIP:hostport/public/landing.js is accessible
but

hostIP:hostport/views/landing.html is giving empty html response.
 While in Localhost these were working fine, c9 is giving problem, and to mention i have started my server using the c9 environment properties

> server.listen(constants.read('port'),constants.read('url'));

Comment: I am having similar problems with static content on Cloud9 over the last day or so.  I have opened a support ticket with them.  I do not have the same problem on my local node install or when I elevate the code to my hosting servers.

Comment: @MattBakaitis can you please let me know the solution once you find. It will be very king of you.

Comment: If I get an answer from them, I'll post it.

Comment: Looks like they fixed it. In the future, I'd suggest opening a support ticket with them.  The more people reporting the same problem, the more likely it will get quick attention.